# "You will be able to ask questions in one days"

Tags: bug, status-completed, plurals

When someone is banned from asking questions, and they have one day left, it says (something like)

> You will be able to ask questions in one days.

It should be

> You will be able to ask questions in one day.

Comment: Watch out for the [incoming giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/291223)

Comment: Yeah, those users who get question-banned are real grammar sticklers. Can't believe this hasn't been reported yet.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't tick to automatically use pluralisations in entity framework, you'll have a stroke.

Comment: *slowly taps giant S in palm*

Comment: @Yvette a Stroke? Or a troke?

Comment: C'mon, english pluralization is piece of cake, and people should be doing it automatically. Try other languages - like Russian, for instance - where on day is Odin(One) Den, but two days is Dva(two) Dnia, and five days is Piat (Five) Dney.

Comment: SO is reputed to be a dotnet application. It probably has access to `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices`. I know this works in English. I don't know if it works in Russian or Arabic or other singular / dual / plural pattern languages.

Comment: Are we sure you'll be allowed to ask question**s** on that date too?

Comment: @SergeyA There are many per-word exceptions based on orthography.

Comment: @SergeyA: English pluralization isn't just adding an `'s'`.  Sometimes it's `'es'` (or `'ies'`) and sometimes it's a whole new word (`mouse` -> `mice`).

Comment: I'm sure there's a jquery plugin for that. */derail complete*

Comment: @CodyGray the user isn't question *banned*, but rate limited.

Comment: @OllieJones as far I remember, they use moonspeak, an in-house library for pluralizations and localizations.

Comment: I have developed an extensive whitespace script to deal with this issue, in all languages. The code follows:

Comment: And this is why I switched to http://ja.stackoverflow.com/. Yeah, you have to completely relearn reading, writing and thinking; but no pluralisation == 0% chance of giant Ss dropping.

Comment: "One days" will make us feel it really longer than "One day" :))

Comment: SO Meta, where pointless nitpicking is a venerated ritual :p

Comment: We should just put a regex in place where every word ending in '-s' is changed to '(s)' and to add it just in case on all other words. Thi(s) allow(s) the user(s) to rely on common sense(s), we can't build code for everything(s).

Comment: This question is about a single plural only, not about many plurals. I suggest retagging from [tag:plurals] to [tag:plural].

Comment: That's the reason why A.I. is still not taking off. Not even grammar can be implemented right.

Comment: @Ollie it isn't just "reputed"; it *is* a dotnet application. When it comes to international translations and pluralization, we actually had to develop a whole new set of tools to work how we wanted - "moonspeak" (I'm surprised it isn't on our public github page, actually, although the related SE.Precompilation is). Obviously something slipped us by.

Comment: I suggest sweeping it under the carpet by changing it from a pluralisation error to an apostrophe-placement error: "You will be able to ask questions in one days' time."

Comment: Ah, found the offending message; "We ask that you wait 1 days before asking again." ?

Comment: @SergeyA please see my answer for a counter-example to your claim that pluralization in English is easy and should be done automatically. Doing it in a way that is easy to develop with and supports all the languages we need, combined with our very exacting performance, build, and export / import requirements, though, is harder again :)

Comment: it is fixed. it now says "We ask that you wait 1 day before asking again."

Comment: @MarcGravell I saw you guys speak about that a number of years ago in Berlin at the launch of de.careers and have wondered ever since... Is there really no standard i18n tool in .NET? No gettext implementation or similar that fit your needs?

Comment: @deceze we do not have typical needs...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be fixed shortly. Basically, we have a syntax that indicates "affects pluralization", and we hadn't used it (the difference between `in $foo$ days` and `in #foo# days`, if you want unnecessarily and unusable detail). This meant it didn't have the necessarily pluralization variants for us to tweak. 2 per variable in English, many more for some other languages.

And to everyone who says pluralization in English is easy: I will note that the UI in this example also used the structure:

> You've asked $NumQuestions$ questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community.

Pluralize that with an automagic framework and I'll be impressed. Sometimes the different pluralization cases simply require different words. In this case, the "`NumQuestions` => single" cases are now:

> You've asked $NumQuestions$ question recently which has not been received very well by the community.

(we choose not to hard-code the number even when we know it is `1`, although "You've asked a question recently..." might also have been valid)